# Copy Protection / Incentive to buy

Tags: commercial

I'm the lead of a small independant team working on a game slated for release next year. Most of the design is collaborative and we are currently investigating copy protection, on which neither of us has previous expertise.

- Our artist does not believes in any protection. While the easiest thing to do, I'm not really happy about it since it means that it will be readily available in pirate form (which will get us potential customers according to artist).
- Our scripter is the complete opposite and wants us to contract a commercial DRM. This is a major no-go for me, on two aspects : it will be a hassle to our clients (as a player, I personally experienced a false positive with a game using DRM) and it will decrease performance.
- My opinion is more nuanced. I've developed a serial key generation algortihm, with verification at the start of the game (only once, if a valid key is entered, it is stored then verified at launch, asked again in case of invalid or banned key). Key verification is only effectued locally (no "phoning home"), as I want to keep client hassle minimal.

As our game is mainly geared towards cooperative LAN play, I proposed that a same key would be able to used several times. Both argued that it will be the same as having no protection. I think it offers the best ratio (incentive to buy)/(customer hassle)

I know that no perfect solution exists and any protection can easily be circumvented. I want to know if any of the community has experience in these matters and share with me his experience or advice : is the described shared serial key **economically** viable (at least, more than no protection at all) ?

Comment: A key that isn't validated online is as good as no key since all it is needed is that torrented copies attach a valid key. I'm with you on the comercial solutions, they do as much, or more, harm than good.

Comment: With 3rd someone can not only reverse you algorith but also: 1. run your game in debugger with bought key with breakpoint setup to syscall open() 2. Step it until he went to code that jumps you to game after valid check 3. Add before open() JMP that jumps to that found place. 4. Distribute on torrents  [ All of this can be trivial if you use some easly-decompilable language like Java or C# ]

Comment: Thanks for your answers ! I can see now why it is not really a good idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Serial keys with purely client-sided validation have really fallen out of favor in the past years. The reason is that without online verification the pirates only need a single valid key which they can place conveniently in the file description for copy&pasting.

That makes the life of the non-paying players just as difficult as for your paying players to unlock their copy.  If you want to offer an incentive to buy, you need to make sure that your paying players need to jump through *less* hoops than the non-paying ones.

Any form of DRM is no solution either. Any software which runs on the users computer is under the users control. It's not a question *if* the DRM will get cracked, it's a question of *when*. All you can hope for is that it will take at least a few days between your official release and the unofficial release on piratebay. The cost is usually only justifiable for projects with AAA budgets. It is also only useful when you have an AAA marketing strategy which uses aggressive (and expensive) advertising focused around the launch date to obtain most sales in the first few days. Independent games usually rely more on viral campaigns which result in purchases distributed over a far longer timespan.

**The best copy protection is to offer your paying players some benefit which the pirates can not.**

One killer-feature is any form of online interaction which requires a personalized account tied to the purchase. When you have a multiplayer mode, consider hosting the game server and don't let anyone connect without a paid account. When that's too expensive, you could host at least a server list / matchmaking service, so the pirates will have a hard time finding someone to play against. When your game is single-player, you could host public scoreboards. Even requiring a purchase to access the official forum can be an incentive to buy.

But not every game is suitable for shoehorning in some form of online interaction just to justify online registration. When it isn't essential to the gameplay, the pirates won't care about it anyway. And when you require a login just to play single-player, they will just build a crack to dummy it out.

Another killer-feature are frequent automatic updates. When you release regular updates after release, your paying players get them automatically through your distribution platform. They get them the moment they are released without them having to do anything. But your non-paying players will have to wait until the pirates have released the update and then again go through the same hassle of finding a working download. After going through this a few times in a row, the non-paying players might consider to become paying players just so they get the updates easily and on time.

But in the end you will have to accept that there will always be freeloaders who will play your game without paying. If you *could* make it impossible to pirate your game, then most of them would not buy it anyway. They would simply not play it at all.

Comment: +1 for the Added Value approach. Give the people who pay extra goodies which increase the amount of fun and interaction with game or community, but let those who don't pay enjoy the game unhindered. Creating games should be done out of passion to be shared with the world, what's the point of spending all of that time if half the people who want to play it aren't allowed access to it? If they're pirating it to begin with, they *never* had the intention of purchasing and DRM isn't going to force them to purchase it, rather just to ignore it.

Comment: Thanks a lot you for your detailed answers !

I do not believe either that a pirate copy = a lost sale.

Matchmaking and online server registration is handled by a dedicated server on our end. As you said, tying online mode and updates to purchase indeed seems to be the best incentive to buy, without hindering players. We plan to add content (new features and scenarios) for at least one year after launch (more if we are successful at generating interest).